# I'm trying to run a query in SQL and I want to know why ADDRESS_LINE_2 is over taking ADDRESS_LINE_1 and showing null

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT    
   EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_FNAME + EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_LNAME +    
         EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_PRIMARY_NUMBER + EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_EMAIL AS EMPLOYEE, 
  ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_1 + ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_2 + ADDRESS.CITY_PROVINCE +   
         ADDRESS.STATE_ABBREVIATION + ADDRESS.POSTAL_CODE AS ADDRESS
FROM         
   EMPLOYEE 
INNER JOIN
  ADDRESS ON EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that no data is null

```
isnull(ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_1, '') 
+ isnull(....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate a string and a null value, the result is null.

Use `coalesce` or `isnull` to make sure that you don't have a null value:

```
ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_1 + COALESCE(ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_2, '')
```

Comment: what if ADDRESS_LINE_1 is null? should be ISNULL(ADDRESS_LINE_1, '')

Comment: @roman M: Yes, you would use it on any field that could be null.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default options for null concatenation with this:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
```

Comment: this is a very bad idea! this feature will be removed from future versions of SQL Server